# Apache + Perl + NTLM/LDAP == Single signon?

Tags: apache, ldap, ntlm, apache-config

We have a Perl app which runs under Apache on Solaris using CGI::Application. That's all running fine. We'd like to get access to the USER_ID variable passed by the IE browser, and do some Database queries and LDAP queries.

I've looked at the Apache documentation and I can't figure out how to achieve this. We don't have internet access (it's an intranet) from the solaris servers so we need to compile everything ourselves.

Does anyone have a check list (or tutorial) of what Apache needs (modules/plugins) in order to achieve this, and how it should be configured?

Comment: In order to give proper response, you might want to include some details on what you want to do with the USER_ID ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are mod_ntlm and mod_ldap plugins for apache which you can use to authenticate.

In your case, i'd assume that you actually do want to use mod_ntlm and ldap or "active directory" is only its backend?

Here's on tutorial that covers the setting up phase: http://sivel.net/2007/05/sso-apache-ad-1/

Compilation phase in the tutorial is aimed for rpm based linux platform though but twiki has some more info about compiling for solaris10 here: http://twiki.org/cgi-bin/view/Codev/NtlmForSolaris10#How_to_build_your_own_mod_ntlm_b

Comment: Yes, absolutely. In other words, you first have to configure Apache to authenticate the user against Active Directory. Only after it has done that will the userID be available to Perl.

Answer (score 3):

## NTLM Winbind

I use the module `auth_ntlm_winbind_module` (`mod_auth_ntlm_winbind.so`) on our server. You need to have Samba and winbind installed, properly configured and running.

You can download the module from the Samba project tree:

```
git clone git://git.samba.org/jerry/mod_auth_ntlm_winbind.git
```

In order to authenticate users via NTLM you have to add the following directives to your directory settings:

```
<Directory /srv/http>
         Allow from all
         AuthName "NTLM Authentication thingy"
         NTLMAuth on
         NTLMAuthHelper "/usr/bin/ntlm_auth --helper-protocol=squid-2.5-ntlmssp"
         NTLMBasicAuthoritative on
         AuthType NTLM
         require valid-user
         AllowOverride all
</Directory>
```

Of course you need to load the module, too:

```
LoadModule auth_ntlm_winbind_module /usr/lib/httpd/modules/mod_auth_ntlm_winbind.so
```

The Windows user account is passed to the application as the REMOTE_USER:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use CGI;
my $query = new CGI;
# get the windows account from the header
my $windows_account = $query->remote_user();
```

Note that IE only sends the user authentication data to trusted sites.

[Here's a website](http://adldap.sourceforge.net/wiki/doku.php?id=mod_auth_ntlm_winbind) with a bit more info on the module.

---

## Direct Authentication via LDAP

Another method is to use the module `authnz_ldap_module` (`mod_authnz_ldap.so`). This is probably loaded by default already. Note that this is not true Single signon as the user is prompted for a password.

```
LoadModule authnz_ldap_module modules/mod_authnz_ldap.so
```

Add this to your directory definition:

```
<Directory /srv/http>
    AuthName "Authentication required"
    AuthType Basic
    AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off
    AuthBasicProvider ldap

    # "protocol://hostname:port/base?attribute?scope?filter" NONE
    # NONE indicates that an unsecure connection should be used for LDAP, i.e. port 389
    AuthLDAPURL "ldap://your.ldap.server.net:389/OU=the,OU=search,OU=node,DC=domain,DC=net?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)" NONE


    # This is only needed if your LDAP server doesn't allow anonymous binds
    AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=AD Bind User,OU=the,OU=bind,OU=node,DC=domain,DC=net"
    AuthLDAPBindPassword super-secret

    Require valid-user
    AllowOverride all
</Directory>
```

[More info about the module.](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authnz_ldap.html)